# Is there ability programly adjust wifi if it is disabled

Tags: android, wifi

Is there ability programly adjust wifi if it is disabled.

— if wifi is disabled:
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
wifiManager.addNetwork(wifiConf)

addNetwork function return -1

— If wifi is enabled it works fine.

---

If wifi is enabled "addNetwork" function works fine and new network is added. In the same situation, but wifi is disabled "addNetwork" function return -1 and new network is not added – Andrey 46 mins ago 
I want adjust wifi even if wifi is disabled

thanks.

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking for. Please explain a little bit more what your problem is.

Comment: If wifi is enabled "addNetwork" function works fine and new network is added. In the same situation, but wifi is disabled "addNetwork" function return -1 and new network is not added

Comment: I want adjust wifi even if wifi is disabled

Comment: you should enable the wifi, and then add the network...After that you can disable the wifi again if you want.

Answer (score 1):

Install the package urfkill.

Use the command...

```
# rfkill unblock wifi
```

...to turn wifi on.

You may need to make sure the hardware switch, if there is one, is in the correct position, too.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if you are currently connected to any network using this

```
ConnectivityManager manager = (ConnectivityManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
manager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectionManager.CONNECTION_WIFI).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED;
```

Comment: If wifi is enabled "addNetwork" function works fine and new network is added.
In the same situation, but wifi is disabled "addNetwork" function return -1 and new network is not added

Comment: I want adjust wifi even if wifi is disabled